# Not able fetch parent object inside a child object

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have established a one to many relationships which are working fine but there is some loophole

I.e

I'm able to fetch the parent and list of children associated with the parent (Parent by parent Id).

I'm able to fetch a child but not able to fetch the parent associated with that child not even a single field.

Inside Company Model class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@JsonIgnoreProperties("company")
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
```

Inside User Model

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
@JsonBackReference
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
private Company company;
```

on top of company class

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
```

on top of the User class

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
```

Comment: why do need to lookup from child to parent ? What is your usecase ? What did you tried so far.. ? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: What does "not able" mean? Does the world stop when you try? Are your fingers cramping when trying to type the code? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: I am listing users at the same I have to display associated company with User

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.